# How to monitor executing of `preStop` command?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to use pod's lifecycle event. Problem is that command from `preStop` doesn't run at all. Is there any way to monitor if it was started? Log of the container is empty.

```
      lifecycle:
        preStop:
          exec:
            command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "/clean.sh" ]
```

Answer (score 7):

I was looking for something, so I added some logging that help to see the logs of the script in the pod's stdout/stderr logs.

so for me, this approach help me

- To write logs to the centralized logging system (help me to check logs in datadog)
- Verify the script is executed properly

```
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/clean.sh > /proc/1/fd/1"]
```

and was able to verify the logs

```
kubectl get pods

kubectl logs -f my_stohook_pod
```

`/proc/PID/fd/1` will help us to redirect script logs stdout/stderr of the container main process.

Comment: works like a charm! Also I've added "2>&1" to redirect stderr to stdout

Answer (score 5):

I just want to add for the `preStop` hook, the pod may be terminated and not available to `describe`.

Another way to see the `preStop` error log is via kubectl events:

```
kubectl get events | grep FailedPreStopHook
```

Example:

```
kubectl get events | grep FailedPreStopHook                                    
5m33s       Warning   FailedPreStopHook   pod/pod-name-59988c4675-79q4p                              
Exec lifecycle hook ([/bin/kill -s SIGQUIT 1]) for Container "container_name" in Pod "pod-name-59988c4675-79q4p_namespace(556dc3d2-9da4-11ea-bca3-00163e01eb9a)" failed - error: 
command '/bin/kill -s SIGQUIT 1' exited with 1: kill: can't kill pid 1: Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#debugging-hook-handlers

> The logs for a Hook handler are not exposed in Pod events. If a handler fails for some reason, it broadcasts an event. [...] For **`PreStop`**, this is the **`FailedPreStopHook`** event. You can see these events by running `kubectl describe pod <pod_name>`. Here is some example output of events from running this command [...]

Comment: Ohh, it means 'no way'. :(
I know the `describe` command, but it shows nothing except `FailedPreStopHook`. It can't help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the logs of  `preStop` hook failure in kubelet logs. I'm not sure if it is the default setting to show `preStop` hook log or need to increase the verbosity of the kubelet log. FWIW, my kubelet is configured with `--v=2` verbosity.